# Adding space between custom scrollbar and content

Tags: css

I have a custom scrollbar as in the following example, I want to add a space between it and the content, adding padding didn't work in this case, and we only see the padding when we reach the end of the scroll.

The space between the scrollbar and the content should always be visible, but I don't know how to achieve this.

```css
#content {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#inner {
  height: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #04246a;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="inner">Inner content</div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach with pseudo-element `::after` with `position: absolute`. To make it effect, you also need to add another wrapper called `content-container` for keeping `content` and `inner` separated.

```css
#content {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

#content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#content::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 6px); /*6px difference from your custom scrollers (1px is from the border)*/
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 6px; /*6px difference from your custom scrollers (1px is from the border)*/
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

#inner {
  height: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #04246a;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="inner">Inner content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to have the same behavior for both x-axis and y-axis, you can try to apply `::before` and `::after` together on both sides

```css
#content {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

#content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#content::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 6px); /*6px difference from your custom scrollers (1px is from the border)*/
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 6px; /*6px difference from your custom scrollers (1px is from the border)*/
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

#content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  width: 20px;
  top: 0;
  right: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

#inner {
  height: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #04246a;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="inner">Inner content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*P/s: I'm using a blue background to differentiate between content and the bottom gap. You can modify it to `inherit` for using `content` background color or any color of your choice*

Comment: I think the OP wants spacing between the red background and the custom scroll bars on both the y and x-axis.

Comment: Thanks but the margin should be between the content and the scrollbar :/

Comment: Just want to clarify with you a bit, @RenaudisNotBillGates. You want that spacing for all scrollers or only for this particular inner content?

Comment: yes it's only for this inner content

Comment: @NickVu It may seem like an obvious solution for both axes, but If you can use a `:before` to space the y-axis this would be a great answer.